# How to nest Parser (IO a) while avoiding unsafePerformIO?

Tags: haskell, io, icu, parsec

While playing around with parsing based on text-icu's `BreakIterator`, I've got stuck on implementing a function like this

```
conditionalParser :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
conditionalParser f a b c = do
        a' <- a
        if f a'
                then b
                else c
```

but with a type

```
conditionalParserIO :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser (IO a) -> Parser (IO a) -> Parser (IO a) -> Parser (IO a)
```

Is it possible without doing `unsafePerformIO`?

So far I could only get to some nested `do`s with the final returned type being `Parser (IO (Parser (IO a)))`, but without any idea how to collapse them.

Comment: I'd suggest you to make the type `conditionalParser :: (b -> Bool) -> Parser b -> Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a` (and similarly for the monadic version). This makes the combinator more versatile, its meaning is more obvious from its type, and also slightly less error prone.

Comment: @Petr Pudlák: In general, yes. I do not plan to use this actual function, though. It simply illustrates the core problem. The parser I'm looking for is significantly different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is to use [`ParsecT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.4/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t%3aParsecT) instead of `Parser`.

```
conditionalParserM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a
conditionalParserM f a b c = do
    a' <- a
    if f a' then b else c
```

This function works with all types of `Monad`s, not just `IO`.

I suppose it's possible to convert from a `ParsecT s u IO a` to a `Parser (IO a)` using [`runParsecT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.4/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3arunParsecT), depending on which `Parser` ([this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.4/docs/Text-Parsec-Text.html) or [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.4/docs/Text-Parsec-String.html)?) you're using. However, I would recommend that you just restructure your code to work with `ParsecT` instead.

---

Clarification

`conditionalParserM` can't be used as a replacement for `conditionalParserIO`. I'm suggesting that you need to change how your program works, because attempting to do what your doing (without `unsafePerformIO`, which you should almost never use) is impossible.

You're looking to compose parsers based on the result of an IO operation, which means that the *parser itself* will perform side effects when it is run. In order to encapsulate this in the type, you need to use a monad transformer instead.

So, to use `conditionalParserM`, you need to restructure your code to work with `ParsecT` instead of `Parser`.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't `Parser (IO a)` equivalent to `ParsecT String () Identity (IO a)`, so it's not as simple as `m` being `IO`? Anyway, I have tried to use `conditionalParserM` as a `conditionalParserIO`, and got a type mismatch: "Expected type: (a -> Bool) -> Parser (IO a) -> ...; Actual type: (a -> Bool) -> ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a -> ...". Could you please clarify how `conditionalParserM` is supposed to be used?

Comment: Attempted to clarify a bit. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: "...compose parsers based on the result of an IO operation": something like that. No side effects, though (AFAICT). This is nothing more than a consequence of `Data.Text.ICU.Break`'s iteration functions returning `IO`s. I guess I could do a prescan to collect all the boundaries in the text, pull `IO` out of the list with `sequence`, and then scan the result with an `IO`-less parser---although this multipass thing is something I would really like to avoid. Let's see if the "it's impossible" answer will hold :)

Comment: If your `IO` operation doesn't actually perform side effects and you're sure it will give you the same value every time, then I suppose it's alright to use `unsafePerformIO`. Just be careful.

Comment: @vpozdyayev I'd recommend using `ParsecT s u IO` rather than hiding `IO` in `unsafePerformIO`. In general, an external library can fail in various ways. And if the library operations were really pure, the original author would have used `unsafe..` to hide `IO` from users. For example, you must be sure that the library is multi-threaded, the operations never fail, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to comment on the difference between `Parsec s u (IO a)` and `ParsecT s u IO a`.

You correctly observed that trying to implement your function using `Parsec (IO a)` yields to `Parser (IO (Parser (IO a))`. Since both `Parser` and `IO` are monads, for both of them we have `join :: m (m a) -> m a`, which allows to collapse double `Parser` or double `IO`. However, in our results we have `IO` and `Parser` interleaved. What we need is some function of type `IO (Parser a) -> Parser (IO a)`. If we had such a function `f` and some `x :: Parser (IO (Parser (IO a))`, we could use it as `liftM f x :: Parser (Parser (IO (IO a)))` and then use `join` and `liftM join` to collapse both parts into desired `Parser (IO a)`.

Unfortunately there is no such general function for swapping two monads. It's not possible to construct such a function without knowing the internals of a monad, and for some monads it's not even possible at all. For example, there is no total function of type `(a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe (a -> b)` (the first monad being `Maybe`, the second one the reader monad `(->) a`).

And this is why we have monad transformers. A monad transformer corresponding to some monad `M` knows how to interleave `M` with another monad. For some monads, such as `Reader`, swapping it with another monad in the above manner is possible and its transformer is doing exactly that. `ReaderT r m a` is defined as `r -> m a` and we can construct:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

swapReader :: (Monad m) => m (Reader r a) -> Reader r (m a)
swapReader = fromReaderT . join . lift . liftM (toReaderT . liftM return)
  where
    -- Helpers to convert ReaderT to Reader and back
    fromReaderT :: (Monad m) => ReaderT r m a -> Reader r (m a)
    fromReaderT = reader . runReaderT
    toReaderT :: (Monad m) => Reader r (m a) -> ReaderT r m a
    toReaderT = ReaderT . runReader
```

We convert `m (Reader r a)` into `ReaderT r m (ReaderT r m a)` by augmenting both the inner and outer part and then just collapse it using `join`.

For other monads, such as `MaybeT`, swapping is impossible (as in the example above with the `(->) a` monad). So their transformers are defined differently, for example `MaybeT m a` is defined as `m (Maybe a)`, not `Maybe (m a)`. Therefore `ReaderT r Maybe a` is isomorphic `MaybeT (ReaderT r) a`! There is just one sensible way how to combine `Reader` and `Maybe` and so both transformers result in the same thing.

Luckily, we don't have to care about this stuff, once somebody defines a transformer for us.
 All we need to know is that the laws hold and how to run the transformer stack at the end.

**So using `ParsecT s u IO a` is the proper solution.** `ParsecT` knows how to interleave parsing within another monad and allows you to combine operations from both of them, without having to deal with the internals.